# Defining a mutable property with a custom setter

Tags: kotlin, constructor

The following class appears in "Kotlin in Action"

```
class Person(val name: String, age: Int) {

  var age: Int = age
    set(newValue) {
      val oldValue = field
      field = newValue
      println("age changed from $oldValue to $newValue")
    }
}
```

My understanding is that two things are happening in the constructor body

1. The `age` property is redefined as a mutable property
2. A custom setter is declared for `age`

Is there a simpler syntax that can achieve the same thing? Specifically is there a way to define a custom setter for a property that is defined as mutable in the property list?

```
class Person(val name: String, var age: Int) {
  // how do I define a custom setter for age?
}
```

Comment: In the first snippet, `age: Int` isn't a property, it's a parameter to the constructor. So the definition of the age _property_ (`var age: Int = age ....`) isn't redefining anything. It's defining a property `age` which is initialized to the value of the parameter `age`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: as [@PaulHicks noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502441/defining-a-mutable-property-with-a-custom-setter/57502736#comment101474362_57502441), in the first example, `age` is not a property, it's just a constructor parameter with the same name, and the property `age` is declared in the body and then just initialized from the constructor parameter. You can tell that by the keyword `var` or `val` missing from `age: Int`.

A property declared in a primary constructor is always a property with a backing field that is initialized from the constructor parameter and can't have custom accessors.

You can, however, make it a private mutable property and provide access to it via a property with a different name with just custom accessors and no backing field as follows:

```
class Person(val name: String, private var myAge: Int) {
    var age: Int 
        get() = myAge
        set(value) {
            val oldValue = myAge
            myAge = value
            println("age changed from $oldValue to $value")
        } 
}
```

Note that the setter now references `myAge` and not `field`. This is called a [backing property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-properties) and is useful, for example, when you want a property to have a different public type than its privately stored value.

Comment: Great explanation, I incorrectly thought that everything in the parentheses following the class name is a property